# Tournaments with no round trips

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T = (V,E)$ be a tournament with no round trips (by which I mean a sequence $v_0, \ldots, v_{k+1}$ of vertices such that for $i<k+1$ we have $(v_i,v_{i+1})\in E$ and $v_0 = v_{k+1}$, for some $k>1$).

This is possible if $V=\{0,\ldots,n\}$ and $E = \{(a,b): a,b\in \{0,\ldots, n\} \text{ and } a < b\}$.

Question: is that the only case up to isomorphism in which a tournament has no round trips?

Comment: Yes, it is a transitive tournament I believe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Transitivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If it has no directed cycles, you can sort it topologically. However, because this is a tournament (i.e. there is an edge between every pair of vertices), then this has to be a total (strict) linear order, which is isomorphic to the one you asked about.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$